# JavaMail SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for ... (Grails)

Tags: grails, groovy, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using javamail from my Grails application (via a service).
Both the from and to addresses being used have the organization domain names.
The same code, when run via command line as a groovy script (on the same server) works as expected.

However, running on the grails server (under war mode) produces the following exception :

```
 javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for ---@---.com

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1873)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1120)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at javax.mail.Transport$send.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at cs.MailService.mail(MailService.groovy:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
```

The code is written as follows :

```
import javax.mail.internet.*
import javax.mail.*
import javax.activation.*

class Mailer {

def static mail(String toAddress, String subject, String body) {
        println "mail called"
        println "${toAddress}, ${subject}, ${body}"

        try {
            def fromAddress = "---@---.com"

            def properties = new Properties()
            properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol","smtp")
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host","---------")

            def sessionInstance = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,null);
            def msg = new MimeMessage(sessionInstance)

            def stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(toAddress,";")
            def toAddressList = []
            while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
                toAddressList.add(new InternetAddress(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString()));
            }
            def to = new InternetAddress[toAddressList.size()]
            to = (InternetAddress[]) toAddressList.toArray(to)
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO,to)
            def from = new InternetAddress(fromAddress)
            msg.setFrom(from);
            msg.setSubject(subject)

            def mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart()
            def mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart()
            mimeBodyPart.setContent("<p style='font-family:calibri;color:blue;font-size:20px;text-align:center;'>"+body+"</p>", "text/html")
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart)

            msg.setContent(mimeMultipart)

            def transporter = sessionInstance.getTransport("smtp")
            transporter.connect()
            transporter.send(msg)
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        def to="---@---.com"
        def subject="Call Scheduler Notification"
        def body='<font face="Segoe UI"><p><b><font color="#6B0667">Hi --- ---,<br><br>Your Call (id: 1281) Was Updated Successfully</b></font></p><table cellpadding="10" bgcolor="#B799B6"><caption><b><font color="#6B0667">Call Details</font></b></caption><tr><td><b>Title</b></td><td>---------</td></tr><tr><td><b>Start</b></td><td>---------</td></tr><tr><td><b>End</b></td><td>---------</td></tr><tr><td><b>Number</b></td><td>---------</td></tr><tr><td><b>Passcode</b></td><td>---------</td></tr><td><b>Special Instructions</b></td><td></td></tr><td><b>Callback Number</b></td><td>---------</td></tr></table><br><p><b><font color="#6B0667">Regards<br>Call Scheduler</b></font></p></font>'
        mail(to, subject, body);
    }

}
```

How do i get past this error ?

**Update :** Still not entirely sure what was wrong here. But resetting all the tcp/ip connections (from the mail server) resolved the issue.

Comment: Something must be different between the command line and grails execution (different address, properties, etc). Try setting `mail.debug=true` in the session properties, and compare the output

Answer (score 1):

You probably [need to authenticate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#norelay).

I don't know why it works from the command line.